# Creating a resource in the using block vs outside the using block

Tags: c#, disposable

For example, a fresh instance of a disposable resource can be created by:

```
var resource = CreateNewResource();
```

What is the difference, if any, in the following styles of coding?

First Style:

```
var resource = CreateNewResource();
using (resource)
{
    //Use resource
}
```

Second style:

```
using (var resource = CreateNewResource())
{
    //Use resource
}
```

Is the first style bad coding practice if we aren't going to use the resource anywhere outside the using block?

Even if we *wish* to use the resource outside the using block, should this *wish* of using a disposable resource outside the using block be encouraged?

Comment: The difference is in dispose time of the instance of the class. In using block, the instance of the class will dispose after going out of the block.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi: I guessed that much. What happens in the first style of coding? Is it just superficial to code by first style? I have seen that style at numerous places.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi: Moreover what happens to the resource in first style?

Comment: @displayName Re: "Moreover what happens to the resource in first style?" See Zuu's answer below.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi Not true - in _both_ cases they will be disposed at the end of the `using` block.  The only difference is in variable scope.

Comment: One other _minor_ difference is that the object is not disposed if there's an exception in the constructor.  It's probably not a _huge_ problem as an object that throws an exception in the constructor probably doesn't need to be disposed, but it is a risk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first noteworthy difference is the fact that, in your first snippet, the variable resource is still declared after the using block, and so someone could use it after it was disposed, which is bad.

```
var resource = CreateNewResource();
using (resource)
{
    //Use resource
}
...
// Unknowingly continues to use resource
resource.BadActOnDisposedObject();
```

If you decidedly want to use and allocate your resources more freely, I would suggest using try/finally, like so:

```
Resource resource = null;
try
{
    // do whatever
    resource = CreateNewResource();
    // continue to do whatever
}
finally
{
    if (resource != null)
    {
        resource.Dispose();
        resource = null;
    }
}
```

This guarantees that your resource is disposed in any case.

Comment: Ok. Clearly the first style that I have seen at multiple places is bad then.

Comment: @displayName Where have you seen it used?  In public code or at your workplace?

Comment: @DStanley: Oops.. I'm trapped. Can't really tell where I saw it. You can make a guess. :D

Comment: @displayName the first of your styles seem to me to be a bit more messy, in that it somewhat suggests very strict control, by the use of "using", but that strictness is lost immediately by the way it's used. I think if you want something less strict, make it obvious from the code structure.

Comment: @displayName Not trying to trap you, just wondering if there are valid use cases for it that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @DStanley: I'm sure you weren't. Though I have seen it elsewhere, I happened to have used that style myself at times (as mentioned in the self-answer) to have more readable code. Not knowing the side-effects of my own code surely is sloppy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. so it is clearly a bad practice.

Pretty well [documented on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx#Anchor_0):

> *You can instantiate the resource object and then pass the variable to
>   the using statement, but this is not a best practice. In this case,
>   the object remains in scope after control leaves the using block even
>   though it will probably no longer have access to its unmanaged
>   resources. In other words, it will no longer be fully initialized. If
>   you try to use the object outside the using block, you risk causing an
>   exception to be thrown. For this reason, it is generally better to
>   instantiate the object in the using statement and limit its scope to
>   the using block.*

I saw this style somewhere online. In my own code whenever the resource declaring statement in style 2 was very long, I pulled the declaration out of `using(){}` and then wrote the code as mentioned in style 1 to make the code more readable.

Comment: If readability is a concern, you can have newlines within the `using()` declaration, and put the inner part on a separate line.

Comment: @DStanley: Sometimes the call is like `var resource = CreateNewResourceByCallingALargeNamedMethod(abc, def, ghi, jklmnopqrstu, vwxyz);` The method has a long name and takes so many long named arguments. Visual Studio wraps the text, breaking it by comma. There just isn't any way to write it which is readable. One can break it to multiple lines, giving each input its own line but that unnecessarily elongates the using block.